# How to parse geoJson file into Leaflet layers

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm interested in different symbology for different geoJson features, based on a criteria available in the geoJson file. I know I can accomplish that with an onEachFeature hook, but I also want the user to have layer control (layer display on/off) over parsed layers.  To do this I create a layerGroup.  I'm a JS and Leaflet novice and am having trouble figuring out how to get the individual feature from the geoJson file added to the layerGroup.

Some of the code:

```
var active = new L.layerGroup();
var inactive = new L.layerGroup();

// kcdfp_parcel is the geoJson file variable
for ( var i=0; i < kcdfp_parcel.features.length; ++i )
    if (kcdfp_parcel.features[i].properties.InActive == 0){  // Inactive=no
// How to add to the active layerGroup????
var overlays = {
    "Active": active,
    "Inactive": inactive};
L.control.layers(overlays).addTo(map);
```

Comment: The code example doesn't use onEachFeature, but an i++ loop.  Is there a reason to select one over the other?

Comment: Found a general purpose method for converting geoJson to Leaflet layers.  Coding is way beyond my level of understanding.  [link]http://jsfiddle.net/mvLe5n39/

Comment: If you know JavaScript just check https://github.com/gagan-bansal/geojson2svg  and here are some examples http://maps-on-blackboard.com/tag/geojson2svg/

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of `onEachFeature` is that it gives you direct access to the layer created for that feature.

Also, if using the `new` keyword, [you have to capitalize the name of the "class"](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#class). Easier just to not use `new`:

```
var active = L.layerGroup();
var inactive = L.layerGroup();

L.geoJson(kcdfp_parcel, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties.InActive == 0) {
            layer.addTo(active);
        } else {
            layer.addTo(inactive);
        }
    } 
})

// the rest as you had it
var overlays = {
    "Active": active,
    "Inactive": inactive
};
L.control.layers(overlays).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not familiar with the "layer" reference.  Is it part of the JS hierarchy?  Or a parameter passed onEachFeature?

Comment: it is a parameter. As leaflet parses each geoJSON feature it converts it to a leaflet "layer" - basically an abstract object that can be displayed on the map

Comment: Thanks.  If you don't mind, I'm also having some issues getting the layers styled.  I found .setStyle and tried that but it's not working.  Every layer is a polygon.  This is the code I added: 'code' L.geoJson(kcdfp_parcel, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties.InActive == 0) {
   layer.setStyle({fillColor: 'red'});
   layer.addTo(active);
        } else {
            layer.setStyle({fillColor: 'blue'});
   layer.addTo(inactive);
        }
    } 
})

Comment: Sorry, haven't figured out how to make sure the code gets highlighted here.  Added the full code to jsfiddle.[link]http://jsfiddle.net/v42aetkd/

Comment: try with featureGroup, use setStyle on that. Updated fiddle but don't have access to the geoJson file: http://jsfiddle.net/v42aetkd/3/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.   I'm also going back over the examples on the Leaflet site.  Eventually I want to tag each polygon and I think at least one of the examples shows how to do that with polygons.(And thanks for the note re: fiddle and the data.  Still learning how best to work with people who contribute here.)

Comment: Couldn't get the setStyle to work on the layerGroups.  I did, however, replicate the method used on the Leaflet tutorial on choropleth maps and got things to work.  Updated fiddle and added some test geoJSON data.  Test areas are along hwy 167 a bit south of Renton.  I'm not comfortable enough with JS and Leaflet to understand the syntax of the L,geoJson style varable yet.  [link]http://jsfiddle.net/v42aetkd/9/.